# How to remove decimal point in an Java Instant data type

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format, java-time, java.time.instant

I get this error whenever I try to remove the decimal point of the Instant datatype in java.

```
! java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: M != java.time.Instant
```

Here is the line of code I am trying to use for the conversion. I am using String.format

```
subCategory.setSla(Instant.parse(String.format("%tM", Instant.ofEpochSecond(dto.getSla().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).getMinute()))));
```

Without the string format, I get something like `24.00000`

I don't want to see the decimal points after 24, how best do you think, it can be handled?

My dto has something like

```
private Instant sla;
```

My dto is returning an `Instant`, that I am very sure of. I want to display just the minute and send just the minute to users in an email. I don't want the default representation with decimal point.

Comment: [mcve] please ...

Comment: `Instant` does not have a  decimal point - it is just an instant in time... its default representation may have a decimal point... but that is not what posted code seems to be retrieving... what exactly do you want to get?

Comment: That is purely display related. Even if you would cut it from parsing/displaying, it would still be stored. You can only alter the output with a `DateTimeFormatter`

Comment: @user16320675 I want to display just the minute and send just the minute to users in an email. I don't want the default representation with decimal point

Comment: @user16320675 using String.format will throw an error, my dto is of Instant type. Thus, I am to provide an instant not a string

Comment: I don't want to use now as I am getting the Instant from somewhere. Why don't you recommend tho?

Comment: String.format("%tM", Instant.now().toEpochMilli()) this won't work for me because of the reasons I stated earlier.

Comment: Again, it won't work. My dto has something like `private Instant sla;` doing dto.getSla using the format you provided won't work is all I am saying. My dto is returning an instant, that I am very sure of

Comment: An `Instant` hasn’t got a minute of hour. It’s a point of time independent of time zone. To have a minute, you need a time zone.

Comment: `String.format("%tM", yourInstant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC))` prints `24` without any decimal point. The same does `String.format("%02d", yourInstant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).getMinute())`. My usual preference would be `yourInstant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("mm"))`, though. It’s a bit longer, but it’s the standard way of formatting date and time data.

Comment: If the user is located in Nepal, do you want the minute in Asia/Kathmandu time zine or the minute in UTC? They are not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
instant                      // Represents a moment as seen in UTC, an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds. 
.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC )  // Returns an `OffsetDateTime` object, converting from `Instant`. 
.getMinute()                 // Returns an `int` primitive value.
```

## Details

You are conflating date-time objects with text. Classes such as `Instant` are not text. These classes use their own internally defined representation of date-time values. That representation is *not* plain text.

Apparently you want to extract just the minute of the hour from an `Instant` object. That class is a basic building-block class in *java.time*. So convert to the more flexible `OffsetDateTime` class.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Extract the minute of hour.

```
int minute = odt.getMinute() ;
```

Example:

```
Instant
.parse( "2023-01-23T19:42:07.123456789Z" )
.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC )
.getMinute()
```

> 42